# In ASP.NET Core 2.2, How to create a custom Registration Form

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Seems like in ASP.NET Core 2.2, authentication is very different. For example, I want to customize both my Registration and Login forms and I can't find them in my project I scaffolded. The work, and clearly I can see them being called with this anchor tag helper:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
</li>
```

in `loginpartial.cshtml1`

What confuses me is  where is the view page /Account/Register and how do I modify it? Where are the model classes I might want to update? All those things use to be in the AccountController but that's now gone.

Comment: depends on what kind of .net core project you created. you now have a concept of razor pages which contains the controller and the view within them and then you have old razor views which will be tied to traditional controller like in .net framework 4.0 or above.

Comment: I chose individual user authentication in vs2019.  There are no razor views in this project.  They must be coming in from DI somehow.  How can I modify my own registration page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to [Scaffold identity into an MVC project with existing authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-with-authorization) to add Identity.

If you are using asp.net core 2.0, you would find it will generates `AccountController`  in `Controllers` folder.

If you are using asp.net core 2.1+, you will find all files in `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml` with Razor Pages structure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @XingZou, when I use the Scaffold to create a register.cshtml, I get a my model generated in codebehind (Register.cshtml.cs). I want to add my own attributes (firstName,lastName). I can add that to the model. How to I reflect that in the aspnetuser schema?

Comment: @Pete If you have your own fields,you need to [customize the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1#customize-the-model) and then add scaffolded identity.

Answer (score 2):

In dot net core 3.1, you have to override registration and login page as they are embedded by default. here is a step by step:

1. Right-click on project
2. Add -> New Scaffolded item..
3. From a left panel, choose: Identity
4. Select Identity
5. Add
6. A popup window will appear. You can choose a page you wish to override
7. Then you will get the custom pages you selected inside
   AccountController

[image: A new custom page(View and CS) will be nested to AccountController]

Comment: It would help if you explained the solution in your answer. Please avoid referring to links as these could disappear in future.

Answer (score 1):

> TL;DR If you read nothing else on this post, [read this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

When you select an authentication mechanism with the .NET Core templates, it includes a Razor Class Library.

For example: `dotnet new razor --auth Individual`

If you crack open the `Startup.cs` file you will see the evidence of the RCL.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
```

This RCL is where the login and registration UI pieces are kept, in a NuGet package.

> See [Reusable Razor UI on MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Your options for options to customize the registration form are:

#### Option #1

Write your own, but don't be discouraged, it's not as hard as it sounds! The ASP.NET Code Generator actually generates the same bit of code, but it's generated in your project so you can customize it.

[dotnet asp-codegenerator on MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

#### Option #2

Since it's open source, you can see the source [here on github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/d27c0100bc8b9b93eb8102b097c20b40f7de9c49/src/Identity/UI/src)

And while I don't know all the steps involved, you could potentially fork it, modify it and package it up as your own RCL.

Hope this sheds some light on where that pesky code is hiding, and a couple of options to try. Of course #1 would be the simplest if you were just getting started.